# Removing/disabling visual feedback in (Ionic) Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

By default `Capacitor` applies visual feedback to `buttons` and `inputs`. On `iOS` this happens in the form of a very brief darkened overlay on the targeted element directly after releasing it. I can't find any documentation on this. Does anyone know how this could be disabled? A while back I noticed it also happens on `Android`, I can't remember the exact visuals.

My buttons and inputs already start out with `all: unset` so it's not plain `CSS`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: it's a webkit thing (...of course). Use `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent` on elements you want to disable the visual feedback on.